# How can I define writable computed observables in Dukescript?

Tags: knockout.js, dukescript

I'm trying to replicate [the example 1](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) on Dukescript, the example consists on modifying the **generated full name** and automatically modify the **first name** and **last name** fields on the data model.

This is my code so far

HTML:

```
<div>First name: <span data-bind="text: firstName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div>Last name: <span data-bind="text: lastName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div class="heading">Hello, <input data-bind="textInput: fullName, valueUpdate: afterkeydown,event: { keyup: fullName() }
"/></div>
```

Java:

```
package org.javapro.dukescript;

import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


@Model (targetId="",className = "WritableComputed", properties = {
    @Property (name = "firstName", type=String.class)
   ,@Property (name = "lastName", type=String.class)
})
class MyClass {

  @ComputedProperty static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  @Function
  static void fullName(WritableComputed model, String value) {
    int lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            // Ignore values with no space character
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) {
              // Update "firstName"
                model.setFirstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); 
              // Update "lastName"
                model.setLastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); 
            }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    WritableComputed wc = new WritableComputed("hello","world");
    wc.applyBindings();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the text field only renders a js function

> function(c,k){var e=b.ko4j;e&&d.java_lang_Class(!1).toJS(d.org_netbeans_html_ko4j_$JsCallbacks$(!1)._VM().org_1netbeans_1html_1ko4j_1Knockout$call$ILjava_1lang_1Object_12Ljava_1lang_1Object_12__Ljava_lang_Object_2Lorg_netbeans_html_ko4j_Knockout_2ILjava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2(e,a,c,k))}

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even if **by default computed properties are read only**, you can make them editable by specifying a function on the annotation `@ComputedProperty` which receives the **Data Model** as parameter and the data that will be used to mutate.

HTML:

```
<div>First name: <span data-bind="text: firstName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div>Last name: <span data-bind="text: lastName, valueUpdate: input"></span></div>
<div class="heading">Hello, <input data-bind="textInput: fullName"/></div>
```

Java:

```
package org.javapro.dukescript;

import net.java.html.json.Model;
import net.java.html.json.ComputedProperty;
import net.java.html.json.Property;
import net.java.html.json.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


@Model (targetId="",className = "WritableComputed", properties = {
    @Property (name = "firstName", type=String.class)
   ,@Property (name = "lastName", type=String.class)
})
class MyClass {

  @ComputedProperty(write="setFullName")
  static String fullName(String firstName, String lastName) {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }

  static void setFullName(WritableComputed model, String value) {
    int lastSpacePos = value.lastIndexOf(" ");
            // Ignore values with no space character
            if (lastSpacePos > 0) {
              // Update "firstName"
                model.setFirstName(value.substring(0, lastSpacePos)); 
              // Update "lastName"
                model.setLastName(value.substring(lastSpacePos + 1)); 
            }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    WritableComputed wc = new WritableComputed("hello","world");
    wc.applyBindings();
  }
}
```